# Update a field by $model->updateAll in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I want to execute this query :

```
update table_name where field=field+1
```

what I'm trying to do is :

```
$model->updateAll(array("field"=>"field+1"),"id = ".$id);
```

field is integer , and after that running this code it updates to 0 .

does this syntax is wrong for `$model->updateAll` ?

do I have to use another function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$model->updateAll` can't do this , the correct function that I should use is:

```
$model->updateCounters(array("field"=>"1"),"id = ".$id);
```